# How do you compare values in two Ansible lists?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I've got two lists in Ansible that I build on the fly using the `find` module

```yaml
- name: "Find all files in {{ backup_path }}"
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths:
      - "{{ backup_path }}"
    get_checksum: true
    recurse: yes
    depth: 2
    patterns: "{{ file_patterns }}"
  register: backup_files

- name: "Find all files in {{ new_path }}"
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths:
      - "{{ new_path }}"
    get_checksum: true
    recurse: yes
    depth: 2
    patterns: "{{ file_patterns }}"
  register: new_files
```

Once I register those variables, I want to run a diff between the `old_files` and `new_files` lists.

```yaml
- name: diff files between new and old
  ansible.builtin.shell: 
    cmd: "diff {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
  register: diff_files
  loop: 
    - "{{ backup_files }}"
    - "{{ new_files }}"
```

I know the above snippet is wrong, but I want to compare the 0th item from new_files to 0th item from old_files n number of times.

The purpose of this playbook is to compare all the files in two directories and replace those that are different.

Comment: You cannot really trust the order in which the files are going to come from the `find` module, so I am not sure your approach is really going to get you what you want. What you are looking to do seems to be a good fit for a [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) task, though, if I am not totally misunderstanding your context.

Comment: Good points! Could potentially add a sort function and separate filename from rest of path for that. Context is the need to upgrade software on a server, and vendor indicated separate actions that need to happen based on whether files are different between existing version and new version.

Comment: It might be that you could use parts from the approach of [Ansible compare two list variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897299/6771046).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε great feedback. I reviewed my approach and found a simpler way rather than building my own index of files and then diffing each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was making this far more complicated than it needed to be, here is what worked that was much simpler. Basically, use `diff -rq \path1 \path2`.

```
- name: diff conf files between new and old
  ansible.builtin.shell: 
    cmd: "diff -rq {{ new_path }}conf {{ backup_path }}conf"
  register: diff_conf_files
  failed_when: diff_conf_files.rc not in [0,1]
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: diff bin files between new and old
  ansible.builtin.shell: 
    cmd: "diff -rq {{ new_path }}bin {{ backup_path }}bin"
  register: diff_bin_files
  failed_when: diff_bin_files.rc not in [0,1]
  ignore_errors: yes
```